# Example for finite dimensional analog of integral transforms

Tags: vector-spaces, intuition, examples-counterexamples, integral-transforms, recurrence-relations

I understand that [integral transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform) are generalisations of the dot product of functions that could be interpreted as infinite dimensional vectors.

The most significant advantage then is that differentiation and integration become multiplication and division.

For intuition purposes I am trying to construct an example which shows that similar effects can be achieved with finite dimensional vectors (e.g. with 10 elements).

So I would start with two vectors and calculate the dot product of them. After that I want do multiplication/division on this resultant term and re-transform it to show that this resulted in the equivalent of differentiation/integration of one of the original vectors.

Obviously for this to work you must use a vector with which you calculate the dot product that is equivalent to the exponential function, so I am thinking along the lines of $2^{-st}$ for that vector. Additionally e.g. differentiation could be understood as differences of the consecutive elements of the respective vector.

**My question**
Something is not working out correctly so that I have difficulties creating this intuitive example - do you understand what I am trying to achieve and if yes could you help me?

Comment: Are you looking for something like the Z-transform?

Comment: @MattL.: To be honest with you I don't know because I don't know the Z-transform well enough. But perhaps you could give an example that contains the elements I asked for in my question?

Comment: Just like the Laplace transform transforms linear differential equations with constant coefficients to algebraic equations, the Z-transform transforms linear difference equations to algebraic equations. So what the Laplace transform is for functions, the Z-transform is for sequences. And sequences of finite length can of course be represented by vectors.

Comment: @MattL.: I had a quick look at it and it looks promising - so first thank you! Could the $z$ also be real valued like e.g. $2$?

Comment: $z$ is in general a complex variable, but it's defined in the whole complex plane, so also on the real line.

Comment: @MattL.: Thank you, what still bothers me with this finite version is that the sum is over infinitely many terms because the dot product is only over the available dimensions.

Comment: The sum has as many terms as there are coefficients. If you transform an infinitely long sequence, you get a sum over infinitely many terms. If you have a finite sequence (a vector) then the number of terms is finite.

Comment: @MattL. Ok, I tried this with vectors but there are still things that don't work out :-( If you gave me an example with the z-transform on vectors where multiplication/division becomes differentiation/integration I would happily accept your answer :-) Thank you

Comment: Integrals are over an infinite number of values, even when the integral is over a finite range. Any discrete analog will probably also be an infinite sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll give a simple example of the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform to see if this is what you mean. Assume you have a sequence $a_n$, $n=0,1,\ldots,N$ and you compute its $\mathcal{Z}$-transform:

$$A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^Na_nz^{-n}$$

This is obviously a dot product if you define two vectors, one with elements $a_n$ and the other with elements $z^{-n}$. Take now as an example a function $B(z)$ defined by

$$B(z)=1-z^{-1}$$

If you multiply $A(z)$ with $B(z)$ you get

$$C(z)=A(z)B(z)=\sum_{n=0}^Na_nz^{-n}-\sum_{n=0}^Na_{n}z^{-(n+1)}=\\
=\sum_{n=0}^Na_nz^{-n}-\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}a_{n-1}z^{-n}=
a_0+\sum_{n=1}^N(a_n-a_{n-1})z^{-n}+a_Nz^{-(N+1)}$$

Transforming back gives

$$c_n=\begin{cases}a_0,&n=0\\a_n-a_{n-1},&0<n\le N\\a_N,&n=N+1\end{cases}$$

So, apart from the first and last value, the new sequence is the sequence of first order differences of the original sequence. Of course, other choices of $B(z)$ are possible and useful.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much indeed! :-)

Comment: I tried this with Mathematica and the vector $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. The result after multiplying with $B(z)$ and transforming back should be $\{1,1,1,1,1\}$ because these are the first differences, right? (I am not sure about the last one, but anyway). Interestingly after multiplying with $B(z)$ I get $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and transforming this back gives the discrete delta function times $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+z-transform+of+%7B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%7D - what's wrong?!?

Comment: @vonjd: Everything ... :) Try this: enter "inverse z-transform of (1-1/z)*(1+2/z+3/z^2+4/z^3+5/z^4)" in WA and don't look at 'Result' but scroll down to 'Values' and 'Alternate forms', then you'll get an all '1' vector (apart from the last value). But it seems that WolframAlpha is not especially good at inverse Z-transforms ...